# trouble with getter method in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, getter-setter

I am having trouble with my getter method when i try to get the point where a person touched the screen.

in my .h file, I have the property

```
@property(nonatomic, assign)CGPoint touchLocation;
```

In my .m file, I have the following code

```
@synthesize touchLocation=_touchLocation;

-(void)userTouchLocation
{
    recognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(locationPressedCoordinates:)];
    [recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

-(void)locationPressedCoordinates:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)rec
{
    CGPoint loc= [rec locationInView:rec.view];
    [self setTouchLocation:loc];
}

-(void)setTouchLocation:(CGPoint)touchLocation
{
    _touchLocation=touchLocation;
}

-(CGPoint)touchLocation
{
    return _touchLocation;
}
```

However when i try and get the location by doing something like
CGPoint foo=[self touchLocation];  it returns the point (0,0).  If I use an NSLog statement to debug my program, my setter method works, but the getter method does not.

Comment: There is no point in using synthesize if you're going to explicitly write the setter and getter, because that's what synthesize do. Don't you get at least a warning for this ? Try removing the getter and setter as you're not doing anything special in them.

Comment: Also, make sure the ivar is declared in your interface, not just the property.

Comment: @eswick - As of Xcode 4.4 thats not required.

Comment: i did all of that, and when i used a NSLog statement to try and debug it.  when i did

-(void)locationPressedCoordinates:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)rec
{
    CGPoint loc= [rec locationInView:rec.view];
    [self setTouchLocation:loc];
**NSLog(@"touch location %f %f", _touchLocation.x, _touchLocation.y);**
}           
it worked, but if i did the nslog statement in any other 
method or in the viewDidLoad method, it still returned the point as (0,0);